# Triage post states it is a duplicate, but is considered "OK"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, disputed-review-audits, triage

While reviewing some posts in the triage I came across the following post: 
[Difference between getters ending with const and const&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54821520/difference-between-getters-ending-with-const-and-const)

the OP himself states

> Althought this question might be a duplicate, I would not close this question, because it might be easier to get to the right answer throught the answer to this question and its possible duplicate link. Basically saying that title of this question is more direct (decriptive), than the title of the duplicate.

I wanted to leave a comment on the post asking which post *"than the title of the duplicate."* refered to. However I couldn't post the comment and got prompted with a message saying "This is an audit" disallowing me to comment from the triage.

The question itself seemed proper and would have hit the "looks OK" button, had the OP not included the footnote about it being a dupe.

But seeing even the OP recognised that this is a dupe I marked it as "Unsalvagable", wondering what the triage consensus was. This prompted me with the message letting me know I failed the triage

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. This question is clear and answerable. While there may be minor flaws, it "Looks OK".

This comes across to me as Stack Overflow acknowledging that duplicated questions are alright, just because a title might (assumption) be more descriptive than the original question.

Wouldn't the proper course of action be to *edit* the title of the original question to make it more descriptive instead. Rather than making a dupe question?

Comment: Note that *"Stack Overflow acknowledging that duplicated questions are alright"* is not the case, triage audits are chosen *automatically* based on a number of conditions, it's considered OK because the system didn't have a reason to consider it not OK

Comment: Can you post the link to your proposed dupe?

Comment: It is the [What is rvalue reference for *this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this?noredirect=1&lq=1). I do not think this is what people put into search when looking for the answer to that. That is why I have put the explanation to the question when it prompted me "Flagged as duplicate..."

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the one. And I totally agree that your title makes it alot more searchable. I just found it an odd question for the triage specifically. But I didn't know then, as Nick A, explains. That those questions are chosen automatically. Which make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so here's the story on this. Positively voted closed-duplicates don't go away and remain easily found even if they have no answers. We allow these to build up as duplicates for search matching and following the duplicate link in the closed-duplicate banner is a lot easier than following the closed-potential duplicate link in the comments revealed by "show more comments."

To get this off the audit queue, open the question and take the opposed action. It won't be selected for audit again.

Comment: take the opposed action **from outside the queue**